# Submitting data to Siebel using Python

Tags: python, automation, autohotkey, browser-automation, siebel

I am looking for advice on how to automate submitting data directly to a Siebel application at work using Python. Currently I enter the data into an Autohotkey GUI and when a button is selected it enters the data into Siebel for me using mouse moves and mouse clicks to select the right entries for each piece of data. Obviously this is prone to errors and I would like to make the application better if possible. Using an object oriented programming language would improve this greatly. Just to clarify, this is NOT for automation testing. The data and account/page that I am submitting too changes quite often. So, modules like Selenium, Mechanize, and BeautifulSoup won't work for this as far as I can tell. Since not everything has a form or a friendly label that I can submit data to. If anyone has experience with Siebel and knows a way to copy data from and submit data directly to different entries that would be great.

Right now my best option is to use modules like Pyautogui and Pywinauto to perform mouse moves and clicks to copy what my Autohotkey script does. But this seems inefficient and potentially prone to errors. There has to be a better way to accomplish the same thing using Python. I am just not certain how and I would appreciate any advice you guys may have. Even if that is "no there is no other way" it would help me figure out what to do next. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that Siebel application web based?

Comment: Yes it is web based and only available from my works internal network

Comment: using Google/Firefox Developer tool to analysis the requests for each actions in Siebel, then using Python Requests or other lib to simulate those requests to perform same actions.

Comment: "The data and account/page that I am submitting [to] changes quite often." What is changing so often that you can't use Selenium, et al?

Comment: The biggest issue is that once I am on the correct account/page the entries that I need to copy from and paste too are pretty much just multiple iframes with a table of data inside of each one. So I could absolutely use selenium or something similar to call the iframe. But it's not going to let me select the EXACT column and row inside of the iframe and table that I need. I like your idea Nic Endo! There are enough visual things on the page I could try identifying by image. I will look into the modules you mentioned. Thank you guys for you input. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Interacting with the Siebel CRM Application can be done in a large number of ways (SOAP, REST, COM, Java, UI, to name a few [supported](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/EAI1/EAI1_Overview.html)) and the use-case and environment typically define the preferred approach. A decent Siebel developer/consultant will be able to help you make the right choice.

The ease and available tooling for automating the UI is largely dependent on the version of Siebel you run. Prior to OpenUI this was mainly the domain of large Test Automation vendors (HP, Mercury, Oracle) and required a separate license module to be purchased.

Post Open UI the web UI itself became a single DOM object and much more suitable to automation using open source test tooling like Selenium. With the Test Automation license module activate it will also introduce [additional HTML attributes](https://oracleimplementationadvisor.wordpress.com/2014/08/05/take-advantage-of-the-swecmdautoon-siebel-test-automation-feature/) that help to create stable locators.

If interacting with the the UI is just a means to change data, then I would advise an alternate approach: directly interact with the business layer. The added advantage is that there is much more information in the data objects than is typically available in a single UI screen and is more structure.

The easiest approach is probably using the web services. The older versions support mainly SOAP but the latest version also support REST. Most programming languages have support for these approaches and will allow you to import their WSDL files. Keep in mind that you're dependent on the DEV team to extend these interfaces too when they add fields to the UI.

Another approach that gives the most flexibility is to directly interact with the business layer using Java (Bean) or COM. The java approach only requires two JAR files and [Google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=siebel%20java%20bean) has enough examples on this approach to explain how to use it. When Python is your preferred approach, then the COM interface is an interesting approach. This [GitHub project](https://github.com/Petka17/py-siebel-com) has some good examples to get you on your way.